# Susubsection problem with titlesec package

Tags: titlesec, section-titles

I want to frame the section numbers and I searched for everywher I did not find the solution[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}

\titleformat{\section}%
    {\bfseries\LARGE }%
    {\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
     \node[xshift=-0.25cm,fill=blue,circle,text=white] {\bfseries\LARGE{}\thesection};
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
    {.75cm}{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}{}
    \renewcommand*{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\titleformat{\subsection}%
    {\bfseries\Large}%
    {\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\node[xshift=0.25cm,fill=olive,circle,text=white] {\sffamily\bfseries\Large{}\thesubsection};
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
    {1.5cm}{\textcolor{olive}{#1}}{}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}%
    {\bfseries\Large}%
    {\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\node[xshift=1cm,fill=orange,circle,text=white] {\sffamily\bfseries\Large{}\thesubsubsection};
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
    {2.5cm}{\textcolor{orange}{#1}}{}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsubsection}{\alph{subsubsection}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter chapter}
\section{ section section section}
\subsection{subsection subsection }
\subsubsection{subsubsection subsubsection}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

desired result
[image]

Comment: could you add a hand drawn sketch of the desired output

Comment: Would something like [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/396264/184389) do the trick? (Knowing that you can add color to the `picture` environment)

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to know my error and why I cannot make other geometric shapes with tikz

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}

\titleformat{\section}%
    {\bfseries\LARGE }%
    {\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, baseline=(x.base)]
     \node[xshift=-0.25cm,fill=blue,circle,text=white] (x) {\bfseries\LARGE{}\thesection};
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
    {.75cm}{}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}

\titleformat{\subsection}%
    {\bfseries\Large}%
    {\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, baseline=(x.base)]
    \node[xshift=0.25cm,fill=olive,circle,text=white] (x) {\sffamily\bfseries\Large{}\thesubsection};
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
    {1.5cm}{}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}%
    {\bfseries\Large}%
    {\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, baseline=(x.base)]
    \node[xshift=1cm,fill=orange,circle,text=white] (x) {\sffamily\bfseries\Large{}\thesubsubsection};
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
    {2.5cm}{}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsubsection}{\alph{subsubsection}}

% make \subsubsection numberd
\addtocounter{secnumdepth}{1}

\begin{document}

\chapter{chapter chapter}
\section{section section section}
\subsection{subsection subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection subsubsection}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Explanation about what is wrong in your example and what I change

1. `\titleformat` accepts only five mandatory arguments, and it seems you give it six (with the sixth argument an empty pair of braces). Also, in the fifth argument you cannot use `#1`. I change every fifth argument of `\titleformat`, which represents the code executed before sectioning command, to empty.
2. By default, `\subsubsection` is the highest sectioning level which is not numbered. The sectioning number depth is controlled by counter `secnumdepth`, so I add 1 to that number.
3. I adjust the baseline of `tikzpicture`, using `baseline=(x.base)` where `x` is the name of node. This makes the sectioning number aligned with title on baseline.

Comment: when i use these packages the titles disappear
           
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage {DejaVuSerif}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=4cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,calc}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titleref}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}